# iOS issue with display controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I trying to show `PKAddPassesViewController` on my view controller with this code:

```
[self.helper alert:@"Attenzione" message:@"Grazie per la registrazzione. Ti aspettiamo in uno dei nostri centri Surfree" delegate:self];

//load StoreCard.pkpass from resource bundle
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"surfree" ofType:@"pkpass"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *error;

//init a pass object with the data
PKPass *pass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];

//init a pass library
PKPassLibrary* passLib = [[PKPassLibrary alloc] init];

//check if pass library contains this pass already
if([passLib containsPass:pass]) {

    //pass already exists in library, show an error message
    UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Pass Exists" message:@"The pass you are trying to add to Passbook is already present." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];

} else {

    //present view controller to add the pass to the library
    PKAddPassesViewController *vc = [[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPass:pass];
    [vc setDelegate:(id)self];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    //[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Logically when this line is called (`[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`) I should see the view controller with my passbook where i can add a passbook into the library, but it doesn't work. Where did I go wrong?

Edit:

Also if i do debug my path object is nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    PKAddPassesViewController *addPassViewController = [[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPass:newPass];
    addPassViewController.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:addPassViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: ` [self addPassViewController animated:YES completion:nil];` in this line you have mistake

Comment: Yes the presentViewController was accidentally removed when I pasted the text and edited it

Comment: it's crashed
`Surfree[2335:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <MFRegistrationViewController: 0x16d52f20>.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e385ecb 0x38b20ce7 0x30c9f17d 0x1749d 0x30dce209 0x30dcdedb 0x30cd57d3 0x30d87c93 0x30c36de9 0x30bafb37 0x2e350ff9 0x2e34e987 0x2e34ecd3 0x2e2b9729 0x2e2b950b 0x332286d3 0x30c1a871 0x1b76d 0x3901eab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: Add a breakpoint in the [self presentviewController] line and check that the addPassViewController is not nil

Comment: And [check this tutorial too](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20785/beginning-passbook-in-ios-6-part-22)

Comment: Is the pass a valid object? Check that the pass is not nil and also have you imported the passKit header? `#import <PassKit/PassKit.h>` ?

Comment: Read please more detaily my question. I wrote that my pass object is nill.
Yes i have imported this header

Comment: Obviously you are not using a valid pass to init the pass with. Debug the error object in the `PKPass *pass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:data error:&error];`

Comment: And here is what the official documentation says about debugging passes: `If the pass doesn’t display and add to Passbook, check the log for a description of what went wrong. When testing in the iOS Simulator app, errors are logged to the system log, which you can view with the Console app. When testing on a device, errors are logged to the device’s console which you can view from the Xcode organizer window. Common errors include malformed JSON files, misspelled keys or values, pass type identifiers that don’t match your certificate, and signatures that omit the WWDR intermediate certificate.`